# Sails JS check if upload file is sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, skipper

When uploading files with Sails JS the server crashes if there is no file sent with the request, considering this to be the controller action:

```
function(req, res) {
  req.file('testFile').upload(function() {
    // do something...
  });
}
```

I have tried to check the headers, but there seems to be no difference between a file being sent or not.

I am looking for something like this:

```
function(req, res) {
  if(file sent) {
    req.file('testFile').upload(...);
  } else {
    // file was not sent, do something else
  }
}
```

Is there a way that I could achieve this behavior of uploading a file or not on the same API?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
req.file('testFile').upload(function (err, uploadedFiles){
  if (err) return res.send(500, err);

  return res.send(200, uploadedFiles);
});
```

Comment: Not exactly, I would like to be able to check it before calling `upload`

Comment: You could easily keep track of that through some variable

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly anwser your question, but at least it is a solution:

```
req.file('testFile').upload(function (err, uploadedFiles){
   if (err) return res.send(500, err);
   if (uploadedFiles.length < 1) {
      return res.badRequest('file missing or could not be uploaded');
   }
   return res.send(200, uploadedFiles);
 });
```

uploadedFiles contains an array of successfully uploaded files, it they were available.